# Changing of default QField basemap when loading shapefiles only

Tags: qgis, basemap, qfield, qfieldsync

I configured a QField Project file for our field data collection. In the QField Properties in QGIS, I set one layer (shapefile) in *Copy* action so that the data that will be collected in the field will store directly inside the shapefile and not create a new geopackage.

Now, our requirement for our field workers is to send only the shapefiles (layer that we used during data collection) to our server since sending the entire QField Project package consumes too much data.

Then, I downloaded the shapefiles from our server and loaded them into QField. However, when I load the shapefiles, the default basemap being loaded is OSM. Is there a way I can change the basemap to other satellite images (e.g. Google Maps/Satellite) or our own raster files? See attached image:

Note: Red dot is the shapefiles collected by our field worker, I simply loaded it in QField, instead of loading the .qgs file

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As it was stated on changelog of 1.9.0 "Taivaskero" QField release:

https://github.com/opengisch/QField/releases/tag/v1.9.0

(chapter "Opening of individual vector/raster datasets"):

"Off the box, when opening individual datasets, QField will automatically add a openstreetmap layer as basemap on top of which the dataset is displayed. But you can add a custom basemap.qgs (or basemap.qgz) QGIS project file in their device's /QField/ directory to customize the layer(s) that will be used as basemap."

I use it and it works. I do not know intented purpose of /QField/basemap subdirectory (maybe for storing basemaps exported during syncing with QField plugin?) but I use it for storing layers, that are connected to the basemap.qgz project.

REMARKS:

- QField directory is located on a root directory of an internal card
  of an Android device or in Android/data/ch.opengis.qfield/files
  subdirectory of an external sdcard.
- I tried using map themes in basemap.qgz project. They works, but when I have choosed an map theme in my project, my loaded shapefile stop showing (as it is not part of the map theme). But I can start showing it again manualy
- In some new release of QField it would be possible to temporarily or permanently set a specific project as the one used as 'basemap' for opening individual datasets in the menu, that pops up when long-pressing a project in the "Recent projects" list (As it is stated in github link in Nelson Silva answer: https://github.com/opengisch/QField/pull/1963).

Answer (score 0):

with the installation, a QField folder is created, where there is a directory called basemaps.
I've never tried it, but I think it's for the user to put their own basemap

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find more info about your needs https://github.com/opengisch/QField/pull/1963